# Android-Not able to write to database

Tags: android, database, sqlite

I am having issue with android app connectivity to SQLite database. I have an instance of SQLite database in Assets folder. 'Select' operation returns the data that is manually inserted into database.But, Write operations (Insert,Update,Delete) are failing. I was using 'this.getReadableDatabase()' and replaced with 'this.getWritableDatabase',  Similarly, 
SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(myPath, null, SQLiteDatabase.OPEN_READONLY) was replaced with SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(myPath, null, SQLiteDatabase.OPEN_READWRITE), but still of no use. I am testing on Samsung Galaxy S i-90003 with 2.3.6 version. Some one please help me

```
    db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
   // values.put(KEY_ID,contact.getId());//Contact Id
    values.put(KEY_NAME, contact.getName()); // Contact Name
    values.put(KEY_IMAGE, contact.getImage()); // Contact Phone
    // Inserting Row
    try {
        if(isTableExists(TABLE_IMAGES,true)) {
            db.insert(TABLE_IMAGES, null, values);
        }
    }catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println("Error inserting:"+e.getMessage());
    }
    db.close(); // Closing database connection

   public boolean isTableExists(String tableName, boolean openDb) {
    if(openDb) {
        if(db == null || !db.isOpen()) {
            db = getWritableDatabase();
        }
        if(!db.isReadOnly()) {
            db.close();
            db = getWritableDatabase();
        }
    }
    Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery("select DISTINCT tbl_name from sqlite_master  where tbl_name = '"+tableName+"'", null);
    if(cursor!=null) {
        if(cursor.getCount()>0) {
            cursor.close();
            return true;
        }
        cursor.close();
    }
    return false;
}
```

Comment: I would double check you are using the `getWritableDatabase` method.

Comment: Are you getting any exceptions ? Using try catch block ?

Comment: there is an exception that says 'cursor not closed'. it points to String myPath = DB_PATH + DATABASE_NAME;
        db = SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(myPath, null, SQLiteDatabase.OPEN_READWRITE);

Comment: where are you runnnig this code? on the main thread? on a separate thread?

Comment: @Doomsknight: using 'getWritableDatabase' is appropriate i believe..isnt it?

Comment: is your database in a writable directory?

Comment: @AndreaDeGaetano: it refers to 'ActivityThread' but no where 'MainThread' .. Am a relatively newbie. Also, the database is in 'Assets' folder.

Comment: @AndreaDeGaetano: your input is helpful. The database i am writing into is located in a folder /data/data/<my package>/databases/. I tried opening this folder through DDMS but it is not accessible.Hence, i believe the permission is restricted. How do i get rid of this

Comment: You would not have access to that folder unless the device is rooted.  I think that's the normal location for a sqlite database.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem seems about write permission on the database.
Android give you this 2 method to manage the creation and upgrade of a new database

```
public class MyDBHandler extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase arg0) {
        //add here the sql code to create the database

    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase arg0, int arg1, int arg2) {
        // everytime you need to change the database place your sql code here

    }
}
```

You should follow this tutorial to understand how to correct it
http://www.techotopia.com/index.php/An_Android_SQLite_Database_Tutorial

Comment: Do you think there is a need to root the device I am currently working on? Is that a solution to my problem?pls

Comment: @Kittu I don't think this is the right way to do it. Alternatively, you can copy the database the first time (or everytime you don't find it available) in a place where you can write on. For example you can copy on the external storage (with the right permission) ... but keep in mind, if it is a shared folder, every app can pontentially read from it.

Comment: Thankyou for the solution.External storage refers to SDCard mounted on to the phone?

Comment: This: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Environment.html#getExternalStorageDirectory%28%29 . BTW, this is not the correct solution to follow.. but it depends on what you want to achieve :)

Comment: My intention is to save image(data path/byte array) to database.This database is specific to my app. so, i am using SQlite and trying to insert byte array form of image. I am planning to have this database in assets folder. Is this a right approach?

Comment: As I previously said, you can't write on the database in your assets folder, the directory is read only.

Comment: btw, if you find my answer good enough to solve the problem, please mark it as the accepted answer (click on the checkmark on my answer)